# Error when Saving into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

So here is the error...

> An error occurred while saving the
>   Panel.
>   System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException:
>   Index was out of range. Must be
>   non-negative and less than the size of
>   the collection. Parameter name: index
>   at
>   System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException()
>   at
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1.get_Item(Int32
>   index) at PanelController.Save(Int32
>   ID, FormCollection FormValues)

During debugging, I checked the parameter it was adding to the save stored proc, and the ID it was adding was 0. Then, when it used this

```
oDal.Execute("Lending.uspPanelSave")
Item.PanelId = oDal.Parameters("@PanelId").Value
```

To retrieve the ID to return it, it set it as 1000? Anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: i'm not convinced there is enough code to analyse this here, the error implies you have a generic list of int's somewhere that you are accessing by index using an int larger than the list size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SqlServer Profiler (in performance tools) to see what is realy send to  SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it's not finding an output parameter called @PanelId in your command object.  Was the parameter added and declared with the correct direction?  Is the parameter declared properly in the stored procedure?

Comment: Direction is declared as follows. It's in the stored proc last I checked.

With oDal.Parameters
                        With .AddWithValue("@PanelId", Item.PanelId)
                            .Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput